# Zend Framework-Unable to Connect to ssl://android.googleapis.com:443. Error #0

Tags: zend-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the *Zend Framework* to try to send *android push notifications*. My application has around 10000 device tokens, While sending push notifications to devices suddenly throwing error:

> Unable to Connect to ssl://android.googleapis.com:443. Error #0.

This issue coming very rarely. **How I can solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Check this [blog](https://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-490) that describes your issue. It states that the `error #0` thing comes from OpenSSL/PHP's openssl extension. There's no way to get a better message, at least not after digging into this for quite some time. There's also no way to assume the error is specifically a peer verification error. In short, PHP itself or maybe OpenSSL hides it from us, and there's little we can do about it. Workaround given is to set `sslcapath` to `/etc/ssl/certs` and since the path varies on platforms, maybe `sslcapath` should be required if `sslverifypeer` is `true`.